# kafka max throughput in MB/Second

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

What is the max throughput of kafka in MB/second.
I am trying to send messages of size 2MB each and get a throughput of about 30 records per second (i.e. 60 MB/second)
I wanted to check what was the theoretical max throughput that could be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is usually network bound -- so it depends on your hardware. Theoretical max for 1Gbit Ethernet would be 125MB/sec.

Also check out this blog post: https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

Comment: In my setup had all processes run locally on same linux box.